# System.Xml reference error

Tags: c#, silverlight, system.xml

I used HtmlAgilityPack in a project and got error that System.Xml 2.0.0.0 was not referenced. I added it from Silverlight folder and it worked. But now I get the same error but it wants version 2.0.5.0. If I add it then it works, but HtmlAgilityPack doesn't work.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Don't copy it into your directory. You need to add an assembly redirection policy in your application config file, which tells the loader to use V2.0.5.0 when V2.0.0.0 is requested.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx

Something like this should do the trick:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml"
                          publicKeyToken="7cec85d7bea7798e"
                          culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0"
                         newVersion="2.0.5.0"/>
     </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
  ...
```

Comment: I can't use that because this is a Mono for Android project.

Comment: So just rebuild the HtmlAgilityPack then with your versions.